# Android app opens and crashes when there is no internet

Tags: android

App opens and works fine when its connected to internet, but when no internet it opens and crashes immediately. I have permissions included. but the error i get is  "MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!"

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

lateinit var networkHelper: NetworkHelper

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar?.title = TITLE
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, MainViewModelFactory(application))
        .get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    networkHelper = NetworkHelper(this)

    loadData()

}


private fun loadData() {

    if (networkHelper.isNetworkConnected()) {

        load_data.setOnClickListener {

            viewModel.tenthChar.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let { char_data_view.text = it }
            })

            viewModel.everyTenthChar.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let { everytenthchar_data_view.text = it }
            })

            viewModel.wordsCount.observe(this, Observer {
                it?.let { wordcount_data_view.text = it }
            })
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_connection_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: show your codes

Comment: post your error logs on logcat and the piece of code highlighted

Comment: com.source.truecallerapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 Process: com.source.truecallerapp, PID: 9544
E/InputDispatcher: channel '2d862a com.source.truecallerapp/com.source.truecallerapp.ui.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to check internet avaibility.

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
            boolean isAvailable;
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            isAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
            return isAvailable;
        }
```

Use Example:

```
if (isInternetAvailiable(context)) {
    //network request here
} else {
    //toast no internet connection
}
```

Comment: Then you need to share your code and crash log for futher assistance.